# Sortable/draggable items like Drupal 7

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, drupal, drupal-7

Where can I find a script like they use in Drupal to drag-sort items.
jQuery UI sortable is too simple.
It should be able to work on tables too, not in lists.
And in Drupal taxonomy it's also possible to take the children's when you drag the parent + go multiple levels deeper or back.

Example image:

[image]

I don't think something like this exists, how hard is it to make this starting from the jQuery ui sortable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this and it's close, doens't work with tables but that's ok for now:
http://code.google.com/p/nestedsortables/

Answer (score 1):

Drupal is an open source project.

You could use the script from drupal itself but its not easy to find it within the Source.
You can find the Drupal Git repository [here](http://drupalcode.org/project/drupal.git/tree/HEAD)

Some weeks ago I developed a little todo app with jQuery ui sortable/dragable and its no very hard to get used to it.

Comment: In case you're wondering the file you're looking for is `DRUPAL_ROOT/misc/tabledrag.js`. It will require quite substantial refactoring to remove it from Drupal as it uses a fair few Drupal-only JS functions